# WebSocket not connecting with react+vite app, with backend running on spring boot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, websocket

My react+vite app is running on the localhost:5173 port and my spring boot is running on localhost:5729. The following is the code for the `App.jsx`:

```js
import { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'

function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([])

  var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5729/cp")

  ws.onmessage=(message)=>{console.log(message); setList([...list,message])};

  return (
    <ul>
      {list.map(element => {
        return (<li>element</li>);
      })
    }
    </ul>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is the configuration class on my spring boot:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
//@ServerEndpoint("/cp")
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new Handler(),"/cp");
    }


    class Handler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

        private List<WebSocketSession> sessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
        @Override
        public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) {
            System.out.println("Session Added: "+session.getId());
            sessions.add(session);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) {
            System.out.println("Closed");
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message){
            for(var t: sessions){
                try {
                    t.sendMessage(message);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I ran the spring boot application first, then ran react application and when I opened console on my react app, it shows:

```bash
App.jsx:7 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5729/cp' failed: 
App.jsx:7 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5729/cp' failed:
```

I have tried clean build (maven), but it still doesn't work and it doesn't show anything on my springboot app, when I run my react app.

I am able to connect using postman.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new websocket instance every time your app component updates (when setList is called). You should create it inside the useEffect hook without a dependency list to create it once if your app component ist loaded like

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5729/cp");
  ws.onmessage=(message)=>{console.log(message); setList([...list,message])};
}, []);
```

I don't know if this fixes your connection problem but that's a problem you would come across next.

Comment: I already tried that but that doesn't solve it. Thanks though ☺️